# Recursive CTE, "cte must be qualified with a dataset (e.g dataset.table)"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, write a recursive cte to iterate over dates to determine if a week or less has passed. CTE isn't found by BigQuery. After testing each cte block, error is occurring at the second part of the recursive cte after the `UNION ALL`.

**Error:**

`Table "cte_test" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).`

**Query:**
sql

```
WITH cte_lag AS(
   id
,  code
,  LAG(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, code ORDER BY start_date ASC) AS previous_start_date
FROM main_table,

cte_test AS(
SELECT
   x.*
,  1 AS lvl
FROM cte_lag AS x
WHERE DATE_DIFF(start_date, previous_start_date, DAY) <= 7

UNION ALL
-- Error occurs here
SELECT 
   y.*, z.lvl +1
FROM cte_test AS y
INNER JOIN cte_lag AS z ON
   y.id = z.id
   AND
   y.code = z.code
)
SELECT * FROM cte_test
```

Comment: A recursive query should start with `WITH RECURSIVE` keyword and you forgot `)` right before comma in 4th line in your query.

Comment: @Jaytiger, adding `RECURSIVE` fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jaytiger, the query should start with `WITH RECURSIVE` since it is a **recursive query**.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_lag AS(
   id
,  code
,  LAG(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, code ORDER BY start_date ASC) AS previous_start_date)
```

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is the right workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.